# what's it called when you're being carried by many people by your hands and feet?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, terminology

What I'm referring to is the situation in which you are being taken somewhere by force (either as a joke or a punishment), by some people who are holding your feet and others your arms; normally you stay suspended off the ground.
I'm pretty sure to have once come across a way to describe all this in one (or two?) word, but I can't remember which. Any help?

Comment: There's [crowd surfing / body surfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowd_surfing), but I can't think of any single word or short expression for *carrying someone aloft **through a crowd, to a place of punishment***. In practice, such a person would normally be ***dragged / manhandled*** (along the ground, much of the time), so the "carried aloft" aspect probably wouldn't be relevant anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**frogmarch** (*verb*)

Here is a definition quoted at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/frogmarch):

> from WordNet 3.0 Copyright 2006 by Princeton University. All rights reserved.
>
> march a person against his will by any method
>   carry someone against his will upside down such that each limb is held by one person

Wiliam Safire of the [NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/10/26/magazine/the-way-we-live-now-10-26-03-on-language-frog-march.html) quotes a slang dictionary from 1873 as saying,

> the manner in which four or more policemen carry a drunken or
>   turbulent man to the station-house. **The victim is held face downwards,
>   one constable being at each shoulder, while the others hold on above
>   the knees.** Often another officer beats time on the recalcitrant hero's
>   posteriors.  [emphasis added]

Here's what [Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frog-march) currently says:

> to seize from behind roughly and forcefully propel forward

So, the meaning may have shifted somewhat to no longer *require* being held aloft, but it's still probably the best single-word choice.

Comment: [Here](https://wordhistories.net/2016/07/08/frogmarch/) is an interesting etymological column about this word, complete with an 19th-century illustration. Excellent find!

Answer (score 2):

What about "carried off". (Of course this has many [possible meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carry%20off).)  The next closest thing that comes to my mind is ["riding a rail"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riding_a_rail).  This, however, is not what you are describing, but it has a name.

There is also ["parading"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parading) someone.  For example: "John was lifted off his chair and paraded down the hall of the dormitory."